# carriage returns or new Line with linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

so i have a problem with carriage return I have web page that have a text area and for a report I need to count how many people wrote in this text area that are save in a sql table call sell and column note

so with linq I do

```
var count_notes = Vmsb.Sell.Where(v => !(v.Note == null || v.Note.Trim() == string.Empty)).Count();
```

Vmsb is my dbcontext

the problem is when my note just have carriage returns or "\r\n", it count it and that is not what I want

the sql that generate is something like this

```
SELECT count(note) FROM [dbo].sell AS v WHERE (( NOT (v.[nota] IS NULL OR N'' = (LTRIM(RTRIM(v.[nota])))))
```

so how can i do to not take in count the "\r\n"

Comment: As far as I can tell, SQL Server's LTRIM/RTRIM functions don't strip some whitespace characters. You could try using `Replace()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I never was aware of the fact that `L/RTRIM` in SQL does not remove newline characters. The only way I can think of is

```
v.Note.Trim().Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "")
```

(sorry Brice, did not see your comment when wrote this)

Of course it is much easier to prevent input like these "empty" strings to enter the database. I would consider a clean up action and adding a gatekeeper to the application.

Comment: that work thank you, yes now I would prevent these "empty" strings to enter the database.